# Big Query converts all timestamps to UTC, is there a way to avoid it for external tables?

Tags: datetime, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, external-tables

I have created some external tables on BigQuery from parquet files. These files have some timestamps(timezone not specified). BigQuery takes the initiative and puts a UTC in front of the timestamp. Is there a way to avoid that? Is there a way for me to tell which timestamps to use?

Comment: Thanks @blami, yes partially. Got more info [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions). It says _This function supports an optional parameter to specify a time zone. If no time zone is specified, the default time zone, UTC, is used._  .So essentially you do not have any option to control it in BigQuery.  Timezone has to be added with the timestamp.